# Windows dig shows no answer section

Tags: windows, dig

I downloaded BIND from https://www.isc.org/download/ and installed it following https://nil.uniza.sk/how-install-dig-dns-tool-windows-7. When I run dig it does not show any answer section. For example:

```
[C:\]dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.14.2 <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: FORMERR, id: 57789
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 2ac0657d3869a2f4 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.                        IN      A

;; Query time: 15 msec
;; SERVER: 172.24.32.222#53(172.24.32.222)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 04 09:53:18 FLE Daylight Time 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to rather be some incompatibility with the server you are querying (`172.24.32.222`), as it responds with status `FORMERR` (it claims the query is malformed).

Is it possible that `172.24.32.222` is running some outdated, possibly noncompliant, DNS software? Without any additional info, I find this more likely than that the problem would be with the current `dig`.
(If the server is indeed outdated and/or noncompliant, then you have the route to the proper solution right there.)

To troubleshoot, and possibly finding a workaround, I would suggest simplifying the query to figure out what specifically makes this server fail.

I would suggest that you try with `+nocookie`, if that doesn't change anything, maybe try `+noedns`.

Comment: Thank you! Both +nocookie and +noedns worked! Dig doesn't give "WARNING: recursion requested but not available" if I add +nocookie or +noedns.

Comment: @tok Out of the two, `+nocookie` is the lesser evil to have as a workaround (it disables a specific EDNS feature rather than all of EDNS).

Comment: Does Dig for Windows have a config file I could put +nocookie permanently?

Comment: @tok Normally that would just be a matter of putting your default options in  `~/.digrc` (ie `.digrc` in your home dir). A quick experiment suggests that it relies on `HOME` having been set to your home dir (generally true in unix-like environments). As for the Windows build, it would probably be better if it knew to use `USERPROFILE` (?) instead. Anyway, if you help it along a little by setting  `HOME`, it all seems to work normally on Windows as well.